# using transform.rotate to mirror a character

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to figure out how to use `transform.rotation` to simply rotate a character 180 degrees, as if the character is sitting in front of a mirror.

Initially, I used the following to set the character model to the game object it is attached to, which works fine:

```
target = gameObject.transform;
origPos = target;
target.transform.rotation = transform.rotation;
```

Now, I would like to turn it around and mirror its movements. How do I do this?

As a first silly attempt, I tried putting a minus sign before `rotation`, thinking that it would negate all `4` values of `w, x, y, z` but of course that was just stupid, as I could not use such an operand here.

What is the simplest way of doing this?

Comment: In case it isn't intuitive: It is not possible to mirror an object simply by rotating it. (Pick up an object from your desk and try it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

transform.scale should be able to sort this, just multiply by -1 on the axis you require so

`transform.scale = new Vector3(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);`

would mirror in the y axis

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localScale.html

Comment: Thank you Al Wyvern. I don't know why it works, because it changes the scale direction!

Comment: It changes the scale size, 1.0f is keeping it the same, if you made it 2.0f it would be twice the scale, 0.5f half the scale and -1.0 is the same size but mirrored etc. So if you wanted to invert in every axis you would say transform.scale = new Vector3(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f) though it's unlikely you'd need to invert on all axis

Answer (score -1):

to rotate something using euler angle values use [Quaternion.Euler](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Euler.html)

```
target.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(x, y, z);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
target.transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(180, transform.up);
```